# android viewpager set current item to 0

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

the first two pages of my ViewPager are always the same, because the adapter doesn't get called when switching to the first element (index 0). All the other fragments work fine. Using the position from `getItem()` returns totally weird positions, so I am using the ViewPager's `getCurrentItem()` method.
TimetableActivity:

```
public class TimetableActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private ViewPager mPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.screen_slide);

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setTitle("Stundenplan");
    actionBar.setIcon(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent)));

    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), mPager);
    mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mPager.getCurrentItem() == 0) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    } else {
        mPager.setCurrentItem(mPager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
    }
}}
```

ScreenSlidePagerAdapter:

```
public class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

private ViewPager pager;

public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, ViewPager pager) {
    super(fm);
    this.pager = pager;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    System.out.println("Current Item: " + pager.getCurrentItem());
    return ScreenSlidePageFragment.newInstance(pager.getCurrentItem());
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 10;
}}
```

ScreenSlidePageFragment:

```
public class ScreenSlidePageFragment extends Fragment {

private List<TableRow> rows;
private int position;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_timetable, container, false);
    return rootView;
}

public static ScreenSlidePageFragment newInstance(int num) {
    ScreenSlidePageFragment f = new ScreenSlidePageFragment();

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("position", num);
    f.setArguments(args);

    return f;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    System.out.println("Called");

    ActionBar actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();
    position = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getInt("position") : 1;

    System.out.println(position);

    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    if (position == 5) {
        actionBar.setTitle("Stundenplan (" + format.format(c.getTime()) + ")");
    } else if (position < 5) {
        int daysBack = 5 - position;
        c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, daysBack * -1);
        actionBar.setTitle("Stundenplan (" + format.format(c.getTime()) + ")");
    } else {
        int daysForward = position - 5;
        c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, daysForward);
        actionBar.setTitle("Stundenplan (" + format.format(c.getTime()) + ")");
    }
}}
```

So the problem is that `getCurrentItem()` seems to be never 0.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

How do you know getCurrentItem is not 0, have you watched its value in debug or noticed the activity doesn't finish when pressing back? Because if it's the second choice you would need to know the FragmentActivity onBackPressed() pops the fragment backstack until it's empty and only then finishes the activity. So you might want to call finish() directly instead of super.onBackPressed().